# How to insert enters into email body in Outlook

Tags: vba

What I'm trying to do is to copy a range from Excel (2 columns) and to paste in into email body in Outlook. I'd like to get also 2 columns in email body but I still receive everything in one line. Here's my code:

```
 Tresc = "Cześć" & vbCr & vbCr & " słówko/a na dzisiaj to:" & vbCr & vbCr & Tresc & vbNewLine

 'utworzenie hiperłącza
  Hiperlacze = "mailto:" & Trim(LCase(Adres)) & _
                  "?subject=" & Tytul & _
                  "&body=" & Tresc
```

Comment: Where is the code that copies/pastes the range from Excel?

Comment: Here's the code:      For i = 1 To ZakresSlowek.Rows.Count
         For j = 1 To ZakresSlowek.Columns.Count
             Tresc = Tresc & " " & ZakresSlowek.Cells(i, j).Value
         Next
         Tresc = Tresc & vbNewLine
     Next
     Tresc = "Cześć" & vbCr & vbCr & " słówko/a na dzisiaj to:" & vbCr & vbCr & Tresc & vbNewLine

Comment: I'd use the much better abstraction `vbNewLine` over `vbCrLf`, but in any case, given that's a `mailto` link I'd suspect you'd need to HTML-encode the actual characters. Your question title is misleading: you're not inserting enters in an **email body**, you're inserting enters in a **mailto link**, which is a very very different thing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon +1, I first tested all types of line breaks on my email sending macro and it was okay. Then I have realized there is a hyperlink in this VBA code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there, instead of putting it in a comment. People may not read the comments and won't see this information.

Comment: If you use `HTMLBody` instead of `body` then you can use `<br />` to create a new line.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the vbCRLF built-in for "carriage return/linefeed" instead of just vbCR.

Comment: I've tried vbCRLF but it doesn't work. Do you think that it might not work due to Outlook settings?

Comment: No, i use it to build Outlook e-mails.  Not sure here.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a mailto-link, there are some other rules in play. Replace the `vbCr` with `"%0D%0A"`.

Example:

```
Tresc = "Cześć%0D%0Asłówko/a na dzisiaj to:" 'etc.
```

Comment: Upvoted for correctness, but it would be better to include the proper terminology, so that the OP and future readers can research everything they need to know about *html encoding*.